# How to copy highlighted cells in excel 2007 from one table to another in the same sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I wanted to copy the highlighted cells from one table to another in the same sheet, but the code that I use always skip the cell before the last cell, How can I edit the code in order to copy all the highlighted cells, and when I run the macro again it just update the second table ?

here is the code:

```
Sub CopyCat()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim c As Range
j = 1
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Worksheets("MB").Range("A15:I60" & LR)
      If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            c.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("MB").Range("J" & j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
Next c
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"

End Sub
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyCat()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Unprotect sheet
        .Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"

        Dim lastRow, row As Long
        Dim cell As Range

        row = 1

        'get last row should start from A15 because i think your table is start at A15.
        lastRow = .Range("A15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

        'loop all cell from desired range of "fromsheetname" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A15:G" & lastRow)

            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

                cell.Copy Destination:=.Range("J" & row)

                row = row + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        'Protect sheet
        .Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Its the same problem, always it skips the highlighted cell that placed before last highlighted cell in the last column, I don't know the problem why, please help ?

Comment: Tell me...your first table is start from which cell and end from which cell of row.

Comment: It starts from A12 to G28, but the user can add rows and columns to the table by macros.

Comment: Ok, Is "A" cell can blank for a data row. Tell me about it. Because we count total row upon A column.

Comment: Yes, it can be blank.

Comment: Oh, I see, that is problem. I think, A cell of your last row not have data. So, that row is not included in process. So, tell me one more. Which column should not empty (between A column and G column). I means, for a data row, which column should not empty(must have value).

Comment: I fill in all the table but it skips the highlighted cell in column D, if I de-highlight the cell in column D ,it skips the highlighted cell in column E, is it hidden rows or columns issue ?

Comment: I think, it is not. Can you post your excel file to other site which can upload some file and show that link in comment.

Comment: Thank you, you can download a copy ,the password for protection is : P@ssw0rd  here is the link http://1drv.ms/1IkqoLY

Comment: I tested your input data with my code in my excel, It works well. I not download your sheet. Just testing with you input data. It is ok. I think that row is somethings wrong. I don't know why?